# Compiling .sh file from Matlab on Windows

Tags: windows, matlab, ubuntu, compilation

I am trying to compile .sh file from MATLAB on Windows. When I type mcc -m filename.m it generates .exe file but I would like to run it on Ubuntu server. Is it possible to make it on Windows?

Comment: Why generate the executable? You can generate the C source, then compile *that* on your Ubuntu server.http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/matlab/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html Look at the -L switch.

Comment: @Bhoke : did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

The .sh file extension is typically used for shell scripts. Check the first line of your file. If it reads

```
!#/bin/bash
```

or so, you are looking at a shell script which has nothing to do with matlab. Instead, you may want to install cygwin to have the usual Linux/Unix shell programming environment available on windows.

Comment: Normally when you type mcc -m filename.m on matlab on linux it provides you  .sh file and you can run it on ubuntu server. But since i have Windows i cant generate .sh file and cant run on ubuntu server

Comment: Yes, this appears to indicate that matlab "compiles" your .m script into a shell script which will likely call linux-based command line tools. Windows .exe files are a totally different approach: these are binary files (not text-based shell scripts), so I would be very surprised if there was cross-platform compatibility between windows and linux in this case. Good luck, though!